# Managing Infragistics Recurring Appointments

Tags: c#, infragistics

We're using NetAdvantage 10.3 to create Recurring Appointment reminders for tasks within our system, but we're only creating/persisting the AppointmentRecurrence object and using it to generate the entire sequence of recurring tasks.  This works fine until someone finishes a task late.

For example - the task is scheduled to recur every 3 months on the 13th of the month, beginning November 13, 2013.  That means a fixed schedule of 2/13/2014, 5/13/2014, 8/13/2014, and 11/13/2014.  If the user completes the 8/13/2014 task on 11/12/2014, the algorithm picks the next reminder as 11/13/2014 instead of 2/13/2015.  Is there anything in the scheduling controls that I can use to adjust the recurrence so GetAppointmentsInRange will fetch the 2/13 appointment instead of the 11/13 one?